# How to find the number of strings between strings in a file/string - python

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x, find

***********************************SOLUTION****************************

After a lot of testings and a few tweaks I have managed to write a working code!

I am sharing it with everyone in case someone is interested in performing the same thing I have.
To everyone who helped - I thank you! :)

```
stringToSearchIn = open('FileName.py').read()

def findBetween(file, firststring, laststring, findstring):
    start = 0
    countfinal = 0
    while True:
        try:
            start = file.index(firststring, start)
        except:
            break
        try:
            end = file.index(laststring, start)
            count = file[start:end].count(findstring)
            countfinal = count + countfinal
            start = end
        except:
            break
     return countfinal

print findBetween(stringToSearchIn, "example", "file", "letters")
```

*********************************END SOLUTION***************************

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time and I believe I over complicated things in my mind.
It is even a bit complicated for me to write, but I will try my best. If something is unclear, feel free to ask!

***Please do not write the code for me. I am here to learn, not to copy :)***

For example:

```
#This is the entire text I want to scan
      s = open('test.py').read()
#I want to go through the entire file and find the string between these two strings:
     stringStartToSearch = "example" 
     stringEndToSearch = "file"
#Next, I want to count the number of times a certain string is located 
#between the previously found string.
     stringSearch = "letters"
```

To further clarify, let's say that this is the string that is found in the "test.py" file:

```
#An example text that I have many letters in, just to give and example for a file.
#It's an example with many letters that I made especially for this file test.
#And these are many letters which should not be counted
```

As you can see, the word "letters" can be found 3 times in this file, **but only 2 times between "example" and "file"**. That is what I want to count.

Does anyone know of an efficient pythonic way to make this happen?

Thank you very much!

***For you sabbahillel***

The script does find the correct string between the 2 given strings, however, stops after it has found it. I need it to keep searching through the entire file, and not stop after it has found.
Also, after I have found the string between those 2 strings I need to run through it and count how many times a certain word is shown. With which command could this be achieved?

```
file = open('testfile.py').read()

def findBetween(file, firstWord, secondWord):
        start = file.index(firstWord)+len(firstWord)
        end = file.index(secondWord, start)
        return file[start:end]

print findBetween(file, "example", "file")
```

Comment: Checking out [string.find()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm) and string slicing would be a good start.

Comment: Also, what if there are consecutive example's or file's in text? I mean something like `... example ... letter ... example ... letter ... file ... `

Comment: What should the result be if the test string is `example something file letters file`?

Comment: @Lafexlos - There would be consecutive example's and file's, and I would like to count all of the times "letters" is found between them.

Comment: So you want to get all `letters` between first `example` and last `file`?

Comment: @Tro - That is a direction I haven't thought of, but since I am searching for a very specific string between very specific strings, I know my file will not consist of any complications like that.

Comment: @Lafexlos Yes, correct. I want to get the count (number of times) the word "letters" shows between "example" and "file". In my example, you can see that the output should be 2.

Comment: I added a mention of using do ... while with the range starting at the index of the end string to get the next set.

Comment: @sabbahillel Using the ".count("file")" I did manage to find the correct number of times it was shown between the strings, thank you! I am still having an issue implanting a correct while loop, though. As I understand, I need to somehow make the end index my start index, to make it continue. Is this correct? If not - could you please further elaborate about the usage of a while loop in this case?

Comment: I added a possibility to my answer. Note that this platform does not have python so I could not run a test. However, I am sure that you can do that and fix whatever misteaks in my suggested code.

Comment: Note if the answer is one that you like feel free to accept it  and/or give it an up vote.  Thanks (:-)

Comment: @sabbahillel I had to tweak it to do exactly what I had in mind, but you helped a lot and I thank you for that. I have shared the solution and it can be found in the original post, in case you are interested. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help Good luck in the future. FYI `countfinal += count` works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that you have the list of strings as you gave it.

[Python Lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm)

list.index(x)

Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

Get the index for your start and the index for the end. If both a begin and an end exist and the index of the end is greater than the index of the start, just process using the range on the start and end indices to get the elements that you want.

Of course, you would have to put in the appropriate error checking and decide what to do if you have a start indicator but reach the end of the list with no end indicator (as an example of an error case that must be handled)

Note that list.index() finds the first occurrence of the start string. If there are more, then start the range at the first occurrence of the end string and do it again. This can be done in an appropriate `do ... while` loop where the while checks to see if there is another occurrence of the start string.

Note that if there is another occurrence of the start string inside the list, it will not be treated as resetting the start but will be just another entry.

```
mylist = ('string' 'start' 'string' 'start' 'string' 'end' 'string)
```

will process

```
('start' 'string' 'start' 'string' 'end')
```

Thus we have now

```
start = 0

while True:
    try:
        start = mylist[start:].index(firststring)
    except:
        # index did not find start string. nothing to do, force exit
        break
    try:
        end = mylist[start:].index(laststring)
        count = mylist[start:end].count(findstring)
        # process findstring
        start = end # set up for the next loop
    except:
        # index did not find end string but did find start
        count = mylist[start:].count(findstring)
        # process findstring
        break # reached the end of the list, exit the while
```

Now that you have the start and end index

Indexing, Slicing, and Matrixes

Because lists are sequences, indexing and slicing work the same way for lists as they do for strings. So just use list[a:b].count(string) with the appropriate slicing indicators..

list.count(obj)

Returns count of how many times obj occurs in list

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me solve my first search of a string between strings. Now I need to create the second part, somehow. I have updated my main post. Kindly review the section under "For you sabbahillel". Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp for find:

```
import re

example = """An example text that I have many letters in, just to give and example for a file.
It's an example with many letters that I made especially for this file test.
And these are many letters which should not be counted"""

found_lines = re.findall('.+example.+letters.+file.+', example)

result = {}
for line in found_lines:
    example_word = line.find('example') + len('example')
    file_word = line.find('file', example_word)
    result[line] = file_word - example_word

print result
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. "result" gives the entire string found in "text", and does not show the number of times the word "letters" was located between "example" and "files". Unfortunately this was not what I was looking for, thank you very much! :)